# Decrypt message using bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть две строчки ввода
Первая это зашифрованное сообщение,
Вторая это ключ (int)
Необходимо конвертировать ключ в 2 байта и
суммировать их, а потом добавить сумму
к каждому символу сообщения и должно
получится декодированное сообщение.

Сообщение :
HlAdghmcXnt

Ключ:
256

Я начал с суммы байтов ключа

```
int_to_bytes = sum(int(input()).to_bytes(2, 'little'))
sum(int_to_bytes)
```

Но как добавить сумму байтов  к каждому символу ??
3 час сижу пытаюсь понять, возможно используя loop но как именно..

Comment: This is russian community, please translate all text or go to english stackoverlow

Comment: @ІванШнір не заметил что на ру коммунити запостил,перевел все на русский.

Comment: Okay, dont worry)

Comment: ImBehindYou ImBehindYou

Comment: @TigerTV.ru а как добраться до этого? каждый символ добавлять по очереди в лупе?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ms85py/48c4654866e7e9758666e5ae698e6f63#file-07_password_hacker_06_creating_bytes-py

Comment: @TigerTV.ru пасиба уже разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

```
dec = "HlAdghmcXnt"
key = 256

int_to_bytes = sum(key.to_bytes(2, 'little'))

for c in dec:
    print(chr(ord(c) + int_to_bytes), end="")
```

Comment: Можно так `print(''.join(chr(ord(c) + int_to_bytes) for c in dec))`